# What practical considrations would a world forever trapped in cold, snow, and ice face?

Tags: society, weather, light, creature-design

I'm building a world - or rather 3 interconnected worlds of cold and ice. The idea is worlds in a snowglobe because of a mis-worded wish of "I wish everything would stay the same forever."

The first might be considered early spring or late fall, where the air temperature is routinely above average, but despite this, the snow never gets a chance to melt. In this world, there is light basically 24/7.

The 2nd is a world where there are quite a few variations of cold, but more routinely at or below average. The light is a lot less.

The 3rd world is a world of darkness. The only light there is the endless expanse of stars and a moon.

So the questions are:

1. How would this affect society as a whole? More specifically the areas of commerce, supply/ demand, and who would be in power because of potential shortages (keep in mind that there aren't many crops that do well in winter, and even greenhouses in the 1st world would probably need to be heated)
2. How would this affect the creatures and monsters? More spcifically how would the cold affect physiology? How would they adapt to the cold? (I don't think permanently having creatures hibernate would be a good solution.)
3. How would this affect the ability to get food?

Comment: Questions of the form, "_how would [massive change X] affect [the entirety of civilisation]_" are just too broad to be answerable, and as such are not a good fit for the site. You may also need to give more detail (like: there are monsters? what is considered a monster in your setting?).

Comment: I'll also point out that snow is not a static substance, it changes behaviour and consistency over time even if the air temperature remains below freezing. You'll be needing magic snow, if you want it to persist in a snowlike-form rather than transition to hard-packed, icey and ultimate glacial forms.

Comment: @StarfishPrime Actually, I accounted for some of that already in the concept of the "snow globe" in which no matter what the snows are always blowing and moving so they won't get a chance to become glaciers.

Comment: Maybe you should explain that in your question. Continuous random winds are kind of an important detail, wouldn't you say? It'll also convert snow to ice dust in short order, and there will _still_ be places it will accrete.

Comment: And your edit says "_more specifically_" twice, asking for two _different_ kinds of specific things. Please ask just one question per question.

Comment: by "above average" do you mean "above freezing"?

Comment: The Inuit people of Alaska, northern Canada, and Greenland have historically lived in a frigid climate. Their vast territory supports only about 160,000 folks...with imported food. So expect a lot of starvation as the warm lands cool.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm no scientist or knowledgeable person, but the environment of your worlds would play a big hand at everything.

For exemple the 3rd world of "endless darkness", everything in there would adapt or be born/created to deal with this almost total lack of light.Most if not all beings would either "sense" the world through their own means(as a dark world does not require eyes) or they would have a dark vision/night vision of sorts(as you said there is light comig from the moon and stars).The organisms here could also end up developing a bioluminescence of their own as means to attract/warn others or just to have their own light source.
Colors probably wouldn't be seen or be considered important as usually you can't see them in the dark, so you're looking for both a nature and a society where dark colors like black, brown and etc are the ones used as they can work as camouflage.Lack of sunlight also means that that people are too pale and thus they need to use dark colors to hide themselves from predators.

As for food in this world, well I don't know how much light plants need to photosynthetize, but I doubt there would be many(if at all) plants in this world due to this.So unless you had plants that don't need the sun's light or don't need to use photosynthesis, life here will be harsh.There might be meat eaters, but they must feed upon herbivores or creatures that don't eat plants/plant-like existences in order to have a proper food chain in place.Without a food chain there isn't much you can do in terms of having animal life here.

Unless as a means to sustain themselves they're able to somehow get nourishment from the moon's light.

This was just an example to one of your worlds, but if you want to know how to do the same with the other two you should search for places with similar conditions to what you set and probably exagerate it a little bit.For this 3rd world I based myself on the deep parts of the oceans, some cave's ecosystems and the north and south poles.